# How to exclude rows searching text between words on vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I want to do a average in column "U", but i want to exclude from that average, rows that have some texts in column "C".
I can specify the text and row i want to exclude but the code will be messed up with long texts, is there a simpler way to do it? Like instead excluding the rows with "**Makro** - Armazém Não Perecíveis Sul" and "Seven **Seas** Maritime Services Portug" in column "C", just search for "**Makro**" or "**Seas**"?

This is the code i have till now:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("mapa_cargas") 'Worksheets("mapa_cargas")
    
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    
Dim arr, arrAV, i As Variant, k As Long
arr = ws.Range("C1:U" & lastRow).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
ReDim arrAV(UBound(arr) - 1) 'redim the average array of a maximum


    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        ' Check if the current array row contains a value to exclude
        If arr(i, 1) <> "Seven Seas Maritime Services Portug" And arr(i, 3) <> "" And arr(i, 17) <> "PC" And arr(i, 19) > "" Then

            arrAV(k) = arr(i, 19): k = k + 1 'place the matching values in the array
        End If
    Next i

    If k > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrAV(k - 1) 'eliminate the empty array elements
        Worksheets("indicadores").Cells(4, 7).Value = Format(WorksheetFunction.average(arrAV), "hh:mm:ss")
    Else
        MsgBox "No values existing to make average on Espera...": Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Try `If InStr(1, CStr(arr(i, 1)), "Seas", vbTextCompare) = 0 And ... Then`.

Comment: That worked!
Can i add other texts with the string "Seas"? or do i have to rewrite the instr method?